# Move pictures from a document into a table of another document using a VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and I need help with a task: I have a Word document that is filled with only pictures that are in a specific order.
I would like to create a macro in VBA that creates a new Word document containing a table with 2 columns and copies all the pictures from the starting document into the fields of the table from left to right and top to bottom. It would also be a plus to then resize the width of the pictures in the table to 9 cm in width.

I know it's probably a simple task, but I'm a beginner and unfortunately I have a certain degree of urgency on this task.

Thanks in advance!

I tried with this code, but it's creating a table with only one row and it's placing the first picture of the document in row 1 column 2 and then I get a runtime error "4605", leaving the table incomplete.

```
Sub MovePictures()
Dim docA As Document
Dim docB As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rng As Range
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim width As Single
Dim height As Single

Set docA = Documents("Doc-A.docx")
Set docB = Documents.Add
Set tbl = docB.Tables.Add(docB.Range(0, 0), 1, 2)
tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed
tbl.Columns(1).width = CentimetersToPoints(9)
tbl.Columns(2).width = CentimetersToPoints(9)

i = 1
j = 1

For Each shp In docA.InlineShapes
    If shp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
        Set rng = tbl.Cell(i, j).Range
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        shp.Range.Copy
        rng.Paste


If j = 2 Then
            j = 1
            i = i + 1
            tbl.Rows.Add
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro where you select all images, convert text to table and then add a column to the table. Use the result to guide you in writing your macro. Also, be aware that claiming urgency on SO is not viewed well.

Comment: Thank you! My bad, I meant that I don't have the time to learn it by myself even if I'm followiong an online course, because my deadline will most likely be before I've learnt to do that. But I didn't mean it as "I need an answer ASAP". Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Just be aware that recorded macros are usually very bad VBA.  To get help on better VBA install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The advantage of recorded macros is that once you know the specific methods and objects to use, you can use the object browser to find a simpler way to do things.